# How to change the default openssl version on Apache

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ssl

I'm currently facing an issue with my openssl configuration.
Indeed, in order to enable tls 1.3 on my apache server, i downloaded the beta opensslv1.1.1-pre7 following the path /usr/local/openssl2 (i renamed it).
The problem is that i'd like to replace the current OpenSSL 1.1.0h with this new one. It is detected in my library, when i use `openssl version`, it replies `OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1-pre7 (beta) 29 May 2018)`, but I still can't find any way to remove the "former" version .
I also tried symlinks but without any concrete results. When I enter `which openssl` it still replies `/usr/bin/openssl`.